# Add supplier code to purchase order line

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

How can i add a the field suppliercode to my purchase.order.line model in odoo
GUI

In the report i was able to do it with

```
<span t-field="line.product_id.seller_ids and line.product_id.seller_ids[0].product_code"/>
```

(not my solution, found it on stackoverflow)

[image: Do I use it like in the picture or in server actions]

Do I use it like in the picture or in server actions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create simple compute field in purchase order line.

```
@api.multi
def get_supplier_code(self):
    product_supplier_info_obj=self.env['product.supplierinfo']
    for line in self:        
        purchase_order=line.order_id
        supplier_info=product_supplier_info_obj.search([('product_tmpl_id','=',line.product_id.product_tmpl_id.id),('name','=',purchase_order.partner_id.id)],limit=1)
        line.product_code=supplier_info.product_code    

product_code=fields.Char(compute="get_supplier_code",store=False,string="purchase Code")
```

This may help you.

Comment: Yes you can use it